# Android: I'm getting a force close message when I modify main.xml file

Tags: android, textview

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView android:text="@+id/customText"
android:id="@+id/customText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:typeface="serif" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**java file:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customText);

tv.setText("Playing...");
setContentView(tv);
```

When I run this, I'm getting a force close message.

I'm new to android dev., many thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: A good tip is to look at the log to see why the application closes.. It often says exactly what is wrong

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but where can I see the log in an android tablet?

Comment: I assume you code in Eclipse?.. then just run your project while the tablet is connected to the computer and you'll have the log in Eclipse.. called Logcat

Comment: Yes I code in Eclipse. Thanks! I found it: Window > Show View > Other > Android > Logcat > Ok

Comment: oh yeah.. forgot you have to add it, if it isnt visible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove `setContentView(tv); below  tv.setText("Playing...");`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need second setContentView();. Your TextView is already inflated to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

As @Vladimir and @Chirag just said, you don't have to use `setContentView()` twice, and in your case, you already have set you activity's layout to `main.xml`

On the other note, I don't think you provide a reference to a `TextView` to the `setContentView()` method (as you've done in the last line of your java code), it is meant to be taking an id of a xml layout file only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project workspace: in Eclipse, click on Project --> Clean. This may be caused by previous errors in the XML file.

If you still have the error, open the XML file with Notepad, rectify it and try cleaning again.